# How can I call Test class ctor with params?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I have unit test class and a `static main` entry method.

I know this is how I run the test class from my main method:

```
public class SingleJUnitTestRunner { 

    public static void main(String... args) throws ClassNotFoundException     
    { 

        String[] classAndMethod = args[0].split("#"); 

        Request request = Request.method(Class.forName(classAndMethod[0]), classAndMethod[1]); 

        Result result = new JUnitCore().run(request); 

        System.exit(result.wasSuccessful() ? 0 : 1); 
    } 
}
```

Is there a way to call a test-calls ctor with params and then run the tests?

Comment: Please don't ask the same issue twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012802/running-test-in-junit-with-params-from-cmd/27018479#27018479

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at the Junit source code and came up with this:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    String[] classAndMethod = args[0].split("#");
    Object[] parameters = new Object[] {"constructor parameter"};

    Class<?> className = Class.forName(classAndMethod[0]);
    String methodName = classAndMethod[1];

    Request request = createRequest(parameters, className, methodName);

    Result result = new JUnitCore().run(request);

    System.exit(result.wasSuccessful() ? 0 : 1);
}

private static Request createRequest(Object[] parameters, Class<?> className, String methodName) {
        Description method = Description.createTestDescription(className, methodName);
        return new ConstructorParameterRequest(className, parameters).filterWith(method);
}
```

Custom `Request` class so that we can use our own runner:

```
public class ConstructorParameterRequest extends Request {

    private Class<?> clazz;
    private Object[] parameters;

    public ConstructorParameterRequest(Class<?> clazz, Object[] parameters) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }

    @Override
    public Runner getRunner() {
        try {
            return new ConstructorParameterRunner(clazz, parameters);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            return new ErrorReportingRunner(clazz, e);
        }
    }

}
```

Custom `Runner` class which creates the test class with constructor parameters. `validateConstructor` has to be overriden because `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner` checks for a zero argument constructor:

```
public class ConstructorParameterRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

    private Object[] parameters;

    public ConstructorParameterRunner(Class<?> clazz, Object[] parameters) throws InitializationError  {
        super(clazz);
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }

    @Override
    protected void validateConstructor(List<Throwable> errors) {
        validateOnlyOneConstructor(errors);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createTest() throws Exception {
        return getTestClass().getOnlyConstructor().newInstance(parameters);
    }

}
```